# I want to add clour manully in barstack plot using ggplot and i am getting error Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I want to make a bar chart. I am using `ggplot2`. There are 37 rows and 5 columns in my data .

Data -

```
structure(list(Cluster_2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0), Cluster_3 = c(1, 
2, 2, 1, 0, 5), Cluster_9 = c(1, 5, 9, 2, 0, 11), Cluster_11 = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cluster_14 = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2)), .Names = c("Cluster_2", 
"Cluster_3", "Cluster_9", "Cluster_11", "Cluster_14"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**Code:**

```
library(reshape2)

matrix$row <- seq_len(nrow(matrix))
dat2 <- melt(matrix, id.vars = "row")


fill_2 <- c("yellow2", "hotpink4" , "brown", "rosybrown2", "seagreen", 
            "royalblue" , "#FFFFCC","#CCFF66", "#99CC00", "#CC9900", 
            "#FF9933", "#CC6666", "#FF3333", "black", "royalblue1", 
            "royalblue2", "royalblue3", "royalblue4", "navy", "chocolate1",
            "chocolate2", "chocolate3" , "chocolate4" , "brown1" , 
            "brown2", "brown3", "brown4", "azure", "azure1", "azure2",
            "azure3", "00FFFF", "33FFCC", "66FF99", "99FFFF", "CCFFFF",
            "006666" )

ggplot(dat2, aes( y=value, x=variable , fill = row  , group= row) ) +
   geom_bar( stat="identity" , position="fill") + 
   guides(fill = FALSE) +
   scale_fill_manual(values= fill_2)
```

**Error:**

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   Removed 83 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

Comment: it is hard to help without a sample of your data, but I assume your row is contiuous (eg numeric) not discrete (eg a factor)

Comment: data example --

Comment: as in your data is just `--`? if you want to include data please edit your question rather than adding as a comment

Comment: I added the data as in image form . Please check the edited question.

Comment: do not add datat as an image. It is not copy/pastable so we still will have trouble helping. type `dput(head(data))` into your console and paste the output into your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [continuous value supplied to discrete scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297196/continuous-value-supplied-to-discrete-scale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `matrix$row` argument is numeric. You can get around this by manually changing it to a character, either before you plot of within the `ggplot` code.

```
ggplot(dat2, aes( y=value, x=variable , fill = as.character(row)  , group= row) ) +
  geom_bar( stat="identity" , position="fill") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= fill_2)
```

**NB:** You don't need the `group = row` part of your code. The `fill` argument groups them.

Comment: Can you please help me with one more error? I want to add legend also but graph did not show any error as well as legends. I used   theme(legend.position="top") but nothing happend

Comment: the guides(fill = false) is removing the legend. get rid of that line